# Animating arrow keeps going outside of my div when my height is set to auto

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue where my animating arrow is going outside of my div when the height is set to auto. Is there any way to prevent the arrow from going outside of the div, while maintaining the height as auto (for responsive purposes)? Any help would be much appreciated.

When I set the height to a fixed height, for example: 300px, the animating arrow completely disappears when it comes to responsiveness; hence, I want to keep the height as auto, while preventing it from going outside of the div.

```css
.title-container-main {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 83%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
}

.title-main{
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #7f1146;
  letter-spacing: 3.5px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: white;

}

.title-main::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    background-color: #7f1146;
    height: 1.5px;
    width: 8%;
    margin: 13px auto 0 auto;
}

.title-container-text{
  line-height: 1.5em;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #674965;
  position: relative;
  font-family: mySecondFont;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: none;
  background-color: white;
}

a.active:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  background-color: white;
  height: 1.5px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px auto 0 auto;
}

.scroll-down {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 45px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    z-index: 100;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #7f1146;
  border-right: 2px solid #7f1146;
  z-index: 9;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-animation: fade_move_down 4s ease-in-out infinite;
    -moz-animation:    fade_move_down 4s ease-in-out infinite;
    animation:         fade_move_down 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}


/*animated scroll arrow animation*/
@-webkit-keyframes fade_move_down {
  0%   { -webkit-transform:translate(0,-10px) rotate(45deg); opacity: 0;  }
  50%  { opacity: 1;  }
  100% { -webkit-transform:translate(0,10px) rotate(45deg); opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade_move_down {
  0%   { -moz-transform:translate(0,-10px) rotate(45deg); opacity: 0;  }
  50%  { opacity: 1;  }
  100% { -moz-transform:translate(0,10px) rotate(45deg); opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes fade_move_down {
  0%   { transform:translate(0,-10px) rotate(45deg); opacity: 0;  }
  50%  { opacity: 1;  }
  100% { transform:translate(0,10px) rotate(45deg); opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
            <div class="title-container-main">
            <h2 class="title-main">TREATMENTS</h2>
            <p class="title-container-text">Some text. 
            <div class="scroll-down"></div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the `.scroll-down` container as a placeholder and you set the dimensions. The width can be 100% and the height needed is easily calculated:

`element_height (25px) + translation_top (10px) + translation_bot (10px) = 45px`

In addition, you can use a pseudo-element (e.g. `:after`) to draw the arrow. We can use absolute positioning, therefore, it will not interfere with the height:

```css
.title-container-main {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 83%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.title-main {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #7f1146;
  letter-spacing: 3.5px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: white;
}

.title-main::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  background-color: #7f1146;
  height: 1.5px;
  width: 8%;
  margin: 13px auto 0 auto;
}

.title-container-text {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #674965;
  position: relative;
  font-family: mySecondFont;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: none;
  background-color: white;
}

a.active:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  background-color: white;
  height: 1.5px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px auto 0 auto;
}

.scroll-down {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.scroll-down:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: -14px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #7f1146;
  border-right: 2px solid #7f1146;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%) rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: translate(0%, 0%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translate(0%, 0%) rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-animation: fade_move_down 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation: fade_move_down 4s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: fade_move_down 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}


/*animated scroll arrow animation*/

@-webkit-keyframes fade_move_down {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -10px) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 10px) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fade_move_down {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate(0, -10px) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate(0, 10px) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fade_move_down {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, -10px) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 10px) rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="title-container-main">
  <h2 class="title-main">TREATMENTS</h2>
  <p class="title-container-text">Some text.</p>
  <div class="scroll-down"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me here. I appreciate your solution and explanation to fully help me understand what it is you have done. Once again, thank you very much! And have a nice day.